# Restore emails on server with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I deleted all my emails on the mail server while playing with `fetchmail`.  Luckily, the mails are still saved in Thunderbird. How do I restore the mail back to remote server with Thunderbird?

Comment: If the server supports IMAP, please see [this](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/switch-pop-imap-account#w_create-the-imap-account).

Comment: My server only supports POP. How do I restore?

Comment: Try requesting the server/site admins if they could restore it at the server side.